# How to pass handlebar item to function?

Tags: handlebars.js

So, let's say that this is part of my code:

`<li data-product-id="{{this.id}}"></li>`

and after a few lines, I have this

`<button id="Button" onclick="addToCart(${{this.id}})">Press</button>`

However, `${{this.id}}` doesn't seem to be right.

What should I write instead?

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of the dollar sign (`$`) is in `addToCart(${{this.id}})`. Are you trying to pass a formatted dollar amount? Or are you trying to do something like a JavaScript template string?

Comment: Just trying out several options. I want to get the specific item by its id. However, because I have used Handlebars I don't know how to get the item.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the dollar sign `$` in the argument to your `onclick` handler is intended for. However, the `onclick` handler is JavaScript and therefore must contain valid JavaScript code.

If the dollar sign is to prepended to the product ID in the `addToCart` argument, then you will need to use quotations in order to make this argument a valid JavaScript string:

```
<button id="Button" onclick="addToCart('${{this.id}}')">Press</button>
```

Perhaps the dollar sign is not intended to be a part of the argument and it is being used mistakenly in a similar way to a JavaScript template string. If this is the case, the quotes will be required in the `addToCart` call *only if* the argument is intended to be a string. If the argument is to be a string, then the template should be:

```
<button id="Button" onclick="addToCart('{{this.id}}')">Press</button>
```

But if the argument is to be a number, then the quotes should not be included:

```
<button id="Button" onclick="addToCart({{this.id}})">Press</button>
```

I have provided a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ytw4bud1/) for reference.

*Update*

To "get" the item is a little more complicated. This is because, one the template is rendered, there is no existing reference to the data that was passed to the template function.

There are different approaches to solving this problem and the solution may be dependant upon your requirements. However, one simple way to render the entire product item object as the argument to `addToCart` would be to `JSON.stringify` the item where it is rendered. This would require writing a Handlebars helper, like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('serialize', obj => JSON.stringify(obj));
```

You would then utilize this helper in your template with:

```
<button id="Button" onclick="addToCart({{serialize this}})">Press</button>
```

I have created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4h6opeu5/).

Comment: @jsnjdhs I would like to know if this was helpful to you.